# Find Menu Link Title given URL alias, to replace node Title in breadcrumbs

Tags: 8, routes, entities, path-aliases, breadcrumbs

In Drupal 8, how can one determine the Menu Link Title of a node, given its URL and other information like its route & parameters?

This is to modify the core path-based breadcrumbs ([`PathBasedBreadcrumbBuilder.php`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!system!src!PathBasedBreadcrumbBuilder.php/8)) to use the Menu Link Title of a node, as breadcrumb link text, rather than the node's Title field.  This would have to be a common requirement, since the default D8 breadcrumbs would be very long in deep menus with wordy titles.  For example, we would need:

> Home > Design > Drupal

instead of the D8 default:

> Home > Introduction to Our Design Services > Drupal 8: The Best CMS for Everything

for all nodes in the "Drupal" sub-menu.

The default breadcrumb service method `PathBasedBreadcrumbBuilder::build` uses a bunch of injected services to look up & check routes to each ancestor pathname of the node URL, then ultimately `TitleResolver::getTitle` to get the titles for those routes.  We would just need a way of looking up the corresponding `MenuLinkContent` instead so we could then get the menu title via `MenuLinkContent::getTitle`.

I have tried to outline the problem for the Drupal Module Development forum ([change Breadcrumbs from Node Title to Menu Link Title](https://www.drupal.org/node/2679881)) but got no response when asking how to simply bridge the gap between the space of URLs/routes and the space of menu link content.  Maybe this means it's not possible without a traversal of the menu: if so I would deeply appreciate some idea of where to start with that approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've got a `RouteMatch` (e.g., your breadcrumb builder passing you the `$route_match` argument), you can use the `MenuLinkManager` service (`@plugin.manager.menu.link`), which when injected into your module could be used like the following (e.g., for the `main` menu):

```
$route_name = $route_match->getRouteName();
$route_parameters = $route_match->getRawParameters()->all();
$route_links = $this->menuLinkManager->
  loadLinksByRoute($route_name, $route_parameters, 'main');
$route_link = reset($route_links);

$menu_title = $route_link->getTitle();
$menu_url = $route_link->getUrlObject();
```

Regarding the breadcrumb implementation: that link and all its ancestors would be also be available via `MenuLinkManager::getParentIds`, as plugin IDs in the reverse order as they would appear in the breadcrumb trail:

```
$menu_plugin_id = $route_link->getPluginId();
$menu_parents = $this->menuLinkManager->getParentIds($menu_plugin_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

The sandbox module "wb_breadcrumbs' did the trick for me: https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/oles89/2367919